# Ocelot swagger redirection issue

Tags: swagger, ocelot

I am trying to implement Ocelot/Swagger/MMLib and .net microservices on my Windows 2019 server.

Everything is working fine, I can call each of the microservices correctly through the API gateway using postman, but I would like to display the swagger documentation as the API is going to be used by a third party.

If I use the ip address/port number I get the correct page displayed, with my microservice definitions. However if I reroute this to a physical url (eg https://siteaddress.com/path/swagger.index.html) I get the main swagger document but a 'Failed to load API definition' error, followed by 'Fetch error undefined /swagger/docs/v1/test.

The network page of my browser inspection gives a 'Http Error 404.0 Not Found'. The requested url is 'https://siteaddress.com:443/swagger/docs/v1/test'.

My ocelot.json is:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/TestSvc/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "test.api",
          "Port": "80"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/TestSvc/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "SwaggerKey": "test"
    }
    ...
  ],
  "SwaggerEndPoints": [
    {
      "Key": "test",
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "Test API",
          "Version": "v1",
          "Url": "http://test.api:80/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
        }
      ]
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

I have tried changing paths in ocelot.json and startup.cs. I can see nothing in the MMLib documentation regarding this scenario, which is surely common in deploying these sites.

Suggestion on where to go next appreciated.

[Page with ipaddress and port number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgEQm.png)

[Page with physical address and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIzAS.png)